# Symfony One to One relation SQL syntax error

Tags: mysql, symfony

I have two Doctrine Entites (AugustusGame and AugustusBoard) that contain a OneToOne relation : every Game has 1 Board and every Board has 1 Game.

AugustusGame :

```
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AGORA\Game\AugustusBundle\Entity\AugustusPlayer", mappedBy="game")
 */
private $players;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="AGORA\Game\AugustusBundle\Entity\AugustusBoard", mappedBy="game",cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $board;
```

AugustusBoard :

```
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * 
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AGORA\Game\AugustusBundle\Entity\AugustusCard", mappedBy="board", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $deck;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AGORA\Game\AugustusBundle\Entity\AugustusCard", mappedBy="board", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $objLine;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="AGORA\Game\AugustusBundle\Entity\AugustusGame", mappedBy="board", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $game;
```

And when I try to get a Game by its ID, it produces badly syntaxed SQL request :

```
$augGame = $this->manager->getRepository('AugustusBundle:AugustusGame')->find($gameId);
```

Like so :

```
'SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t10.id AS id_11, t10.tokenBag AS tokenBag_12
FROM augustus_game t0 
LEFT JOIN augustus_board t10 ON WHERE t0.id = 16'
```

Obviously it's not the good way to write a LEFT JOIN, but since it's generated by Symfony I wonder how to fix this.

Do you have any idea of what could cause this ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [Doctrine Docs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/unitofwork-associations.html) on how to deal with the owning side and inverse side of a bidirectional onetoone relationship.

Your problem here is that you declared both entities as the owning side. Change the `mappedBy` attribute on one entity to `inversedBy` and you should be fine.